# Convert element to css selector in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, xpath, css-selectors, lxml.html

I'm trying to convert the following element:

```
@[width="300"]
```

That I convert to xpath as:

```
//*[@width="300"]
```

To a css selector. Because with lxml if I run:

```
selector = "@[width="300"]"
tree = lxml.html.fromstring(fparse(fileIn).to_string())
tree.cssselect(selector)
```

I get the following error:

```
Expected selector, got <DELIM '@' at 0>
```

How can I convert it **without using external libraries not included in lxml itself**? I need to use cssselect and not xpath because I have other cases where my program need to parse selectors like the following one:

```
@[width="300"] > p > a
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need the `@` for attribute definition in a CSS selector:

```
[width="300"]
```

Double quotes are actually extra for this particular value (as long as an attribute value is *alphanumeric*):

```
[width=300]
```